# Use analytics tool to tie browser behavior to back end transactions

Tags: logging, transactions, google-analytics, analytics

Can I use an analytics tool like Google Analytics to tie user behavior to back end (Java) transactions?  I know I can use the analytics API to store custom data, like an account number or something that I can tie to the log/database created from the Java classes, but is this the best way?

What I want to do is see how many users access each page, but also be able to recreate all steps a user performed - they went to the signup page and entered a particular user name, which was submitted to the Java controller and returned user ID X.  I don't want to do it all on the javascript side - it seems like there is a limit of the number of custom events I can store, and I want to log things that don't make sense to pass back to the page, like the database response time.

Is this feasible using any analytics tool (it doesn't need to be Google Analytics), or should I use such a tool, then have separate logging from the Java side for database response times, return values, etc?